# Unexpected token error on my for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax

```
function count(num){
    var nums=[];

    for(i=1;i<num){
        var n=Integer.toString(i);
        nums.add(n);
        i++;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

I'm getting an error on my for loop

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? The code is not valid Java.

Comment: What error you are encountering?

Comment: Increment `i` in the loop declaration, rather than the loop body.

Comment: use `for(i=1; i<num; i++)` , why you are writing `i++;` outside if you are not making any changes to it.

Comment: Besides the syntax error in the for statement, you probably want `.push()`, not `.add()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

`for (i = 0; i < num;)`

for-loops take in 3 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need do this in javascript:

```
function count(num){
    var nums=[];
    for(var i=1;i<num;i++){
        nums.push(i);
    }
    return nums;
}
```